# Broken dependency reference for .NETCoreApp

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am on a project where we are using .NET core within Visual Studio 2015.

I am seeing a lot of broken references, and I am unsure if I am supposed to download them from the internet or if I should obtain them from the client.

I am seeing `.NETCoreApp, Version=v1.1` and - underneath it in the tree - a lot of Microsoft.AspNetCore.xx which are broken. So, what is this reference -- `.NETCoreApp, Version=v1.1`?

I would post a picture, if I could.

Comment: vs 2015 only works with .net core 1.x which is kind of old school by now. If you are starting a new project you should use vs 2017 and the 2.0 .net core sdk

Comment: Agreed. VS2017 was a little rough at release, but now it's acceptably stable. There's no reason not to upgrade, and you'll save yourself a lot of pain and effort by doing so.

Comment: It's a requirement with the client to use 2015 ... And, in all fairness, they do have a .sln on their machine that works. Although, it has been a nightmare to set all this up on my own machine